# Define a property in python

Tags: python

I have a class like this:

```
class MyItem:

    def __init__(self):
        self.person = None
        self.place = None            
        self.thing = None # property
```

However I also want to define a property for one of the attributes, for example:

```
@property
def thing(self):
    return self.person + self.place
```

In other words, I want to make my initialization show all my variables so it's explicit, but I want to "override" one of those attributes with a class property. How would I do this?

As an example of what I currently have:

```
class MyItem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.person = None
        self.place = None            
        self.thing = None # property
    @property
    def thing(self):
        return self.person + self.place

m=MyItem()
m.person='A'
m.place='B'
print m.thing
>>> None
```

Comment: It could either go in English in the `__init__` docstring, or as a comment underneath `self.place`

Comment: So what exactly is preventing you? Are you getting any errors when you try the above? What have you researched?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga when I try the above, it uses the attribute within `__init__` and not the property.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga question updated.

Comment: Why are you assigning to `self.thing` if it's supposed to be a property?

Comment: @Barmar I just want self.thing to be a property, so it prints out "AB" when I type in `m.thing`. However, I want to "define it" in the `__init__` just to be explicit -- i.e., so all my variables are at the top if someone wants to see everything that can be defined (and not have to scroll down 200 lines to see all function calls, etc.)

Comment: That won't work. Assigning to the object attribute overrides the class property. That's why @SyntaxVoid suggested putting it in a comment or the docstring.

Comment: @Barmar ah, got it. So that's essentially the answer I'm looking for. Want to put it in an answer?

Comment: @FI-Info Does it really warrant an answer?

Comment: @Barmar no it shouldn't do that, it should throw an exception because the property doesn't define a setter. The problem is the OP is using Python 2 and didn't inherit from `object` explicitly. You can get the behavior the OP wants using a dummy setter, but I would personally advise against that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this isn't the answer you're looking for, but my advice:

**Don't define `MyItem.thing` in more than one place.**

That would be confusing and probably give you heartburn in the long run. And the short run.

The thing is that `MyItem.__init__()` is not documentation, it's just defining how instantiation happens. Documentation is documentation and unfortunately it is a bit of a hassle to write sometimes. Have a look at [`sphinx`'s `autodoc`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#module-sphinx.ext.autodoc) and/or the [`pdoc3`](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc/doc/pdoc/) project to see how these tools can write your docs for you, based on your classes, properties, methods, etc.

Here's how I would do it:

```
class MyItem:
    """
    Defines an item.

    Attributes
    ----------
        person: A person.
        place: A place.

    Properties
    ----------
        thing: A thing, the sum of person and place.

    Methods
    -------
        There aren't any, but there will be!
    """
    def __init__(self, person=None, place=None):
        self.person = person
        self.place = place

    @property
    def thing(self):
        """
        Property of MyItem instance. The sum of person and place,
        if both of those things exist.

        Returns
        -------
        str. The sum of the person and place attributes.
        """
        if (self.person is not None) and (self.place is not None):
            return self.person + self.place
        else:
            return None

m = MyItem('A', 'B')
print(m.thing)
```

This returns:

```
'AB'
```

I'd also start using Python 3 as soon as possible.

Comment: How does this solve the OP's problem of wanting to show in the `__init__` method that there's a `thing` property?

Comment: Hm, well.... it doesn't, that bit didn't sink in. But now that it has, I don't understand the requirement.

Comment: For some reason he thinks the `__init__` method should be the self-documentation of the class attributes.

Comment: Okay, tried to reflect what I think about that idea. Cheers.

Comment: @kwinkunks where/how would you define, in your documentation, the class variables and methods? Or would you not do that and just put those docs in the respective method?

Comment: @FI-Info Each method would have its own docstring. I generally rely on autodoc to get everything else from the code (and its docstrings).

Answer (score 2):

There are two things wrong here. Firstly, your code as written is allowing the shadowing of a property by an instance attribute **because you are on Python 2** and have not inherited from object, the descriptor protocol requires new-style classes to work properly. So, note what happens when we do this:

```
class MyItem(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.person = None
        self.place = None
        self.thing = None # property
    @property
    def thing(self):
        return self.person + self.place

m=MyItem()
m.person='A'
m.place='B'
print m.thing
```

The output should be:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    m=MyItem()
  File "test.py", line 5, in __init__
    self.thing = None # property
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Which is what we should expect, since we haven't created a setter. I would argue this is the *behavior you would want*. However, there is nothing stopping you from implementing a setter that simply does nothing:

```
class MyItem(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.person = None
        self.place = None
        self.thing = None # property
    @property
    def thing(self):
        return self.person + self.place
    @thing.setter
    def thing(self, val):
        pass

m=MyItem()
m.person='A'
m.place='B'
print m.thing
```

Which now ouputs:

```
AB
```

Although, I consider this an example of failing silently in a way that will probably cause headaches down the road. I would strongly advise against doing this, but it's possible.

Comment: You could make the setter check if the value is `None`, and throw an error otherwise.

Comment: @Barmar that's a possibility. Still, seems just a bad idea to me all around

Comment: Well, the original goal is misguided, there are no good solutions, just less-bad ones.